# Cannot deserialize the JSON array to object

Tags: c#, json

```
    string res = "{\"ArastirmaRaporListesiResult\":{\"Data\":[{\"Baslik\":\"Akbank\",\"DosyaAd\":\"66245_AKBNK_27062022_OtomatikBUlten.pdf\",\"EnstrumanKod\":\"AKBNK\",\"KategoriAd\":\"Şirket Notu\",\"KategoriKod\":\"SIRKETRAPOR\",\"RaporId\":27573,\"RaporTarih\":\"27.06.2022\",\"Url\":\"http:\"},{\"Baslik\":\"Bim Mağazalar\",\"DosyaAd\":\"66243_BIMAS_27062022_OtomatikBUlten.pdf\",\"EnstrumanKod\":\"BIMAS\",\"KategoriAd\":\"Şirket Notu\",\"KategoriKod\":\"SIRKETRAPOR\",\"RaporId\":27571,\"RaporTarih\":\"27.06.2022\",\"Url\":\"http:\"}],\"ErrorCode\":0,\"ErrorMessage\":null,\"StatusCode\":200}}";

    public class Result
    {
        public List<Data> Datas { get; set; }
        public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public string Baslik { get; set; }
        public string DosyaAd { get; set; }
        public string EnstrumanKod { get; set; }
        public string KategoriAd { get; set; }
        public string KategoriKod { get; set; }
        public string RaporId { get; set; }
        public string RaporTarih { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }

    var arastirmaContracts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List< Result>>(res);
```

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Finnet.Program+ArastirmaRaporListesiResults]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
> Path 'ArastirmaRaporListesiResult', line 1, position 31.

Comment: The error is clear. This JSON string isn't an array, it's an object with a property named `ArastirmaRaporListesiResult`. Use the correct class for deserialization or create one that actually matches the JSON string

Comment: How should I change the Result and Data classes.

Comment: You don't. The JSON string you posted contains a *different* object, one with a single `ArastirmaRaporListesiResult` property which contains what looks like a `Result` object. There are several online JSON->C# generators that can generate DTOs from a JSON string. Even Visual Studio can do that, using the `Paste Special > Paste As JSON` command in the Edit menu

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yeah that's the way. But be careful: the Pasting as JSON takes arrays instead of lists and also the types can be confusing. Most time there can be some other types e.g. float and double. So take a closer look to the result.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing i noticed is that your Result class will be trying to bind to a property called "Datas" where as the json string suggests it should be called "Data".
Based on the json string I think you should try to deserialize to:

```
public partial class Result
{
    public ArastirmaRaporListesiResult ArastirmaRaporListesiResult { get; set; }
}

public partial class ArastirmaRaporListesiResult
{
    public Datum[] Data { get; set; }
    public long ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public object ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public long StatusCode { get; set; }
}

public partial class Datum
{
    public string Baslik { get; set; }
    public string DosyaAd { get; set; }
    public string EnstrumanKod { get; set; }
    public string KategoriAd { get; set; }
    public string KategoriKod { get; set; }
    public long RaporId { get; set; }
    public string RaporTarih { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

For reference I used https://app.quicktype.io/ to generate the class

Answer (score -1):

```
public class ArastirmaRaporListesiResult
{
    public List<Datum> Data { get; set; }
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public object ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
}
public class Datum
{
    public string Baslik { get; set; }
    public string DosyaAd { get; set; }
    public string EnstrumanKod { get; set; }
    public string KategoriAd { get; set; }
    public string KategoriKod { get; set; }
    public int RaporId { get; set; }
    public string RaporTarih { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
public class Root
{
    public ArastirmaRaporListesiResult ArastirmaRaporListesiResult { get; set; }
}
```

Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJsonResponse);

It works in this state.
Thanks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).